# Copy files with different extensions to different basename with same extensions

Tags: cp, fish

I have 3 files

```
Original.js
Original.vue
Original.css
```

How can I easily copy them to

```
Copy.js
Copy.vue
Copy.css
```

Until now, i always just copied one by one, but if I could use something like `copy Original.* Copy.*`, that would be awesome.

I use the fish shell, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`string replace`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html#replace-subcommand)

```
for file in Original.*
  cp $file (string replace Original Copy $file)
end
```